# For/While loop struggles with async calls

Tags: protractor

am trying to check element on regular interval and click only if it is present. Some times this element appears in 2-3 minutes. If it is not present, i want to wait for few seconds and then refresh page

Here is what i tried:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 60; i++){
    element(that.proposalByOrderPath(num)).isPresent().then(function(result){
        if(result){
            console.log(i);
            return element(that.proposalByOrderPath(num)).click();
        }
        else{
            browser.sleep(15000);
            browser.refresh();
       }
    });
}
```

As an output, it prints 60 twice. It clicks on the element once but tries to look again for the element and throws "element not visible" error.

Comment: Maybe you need to set the element's `visible` field to `true` before clicking on it?

Comment: main issue is loop gets done before it goes to check element

Answer (score 0):

This is a closure issue. For more understanding read the following-

[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Answer (score 0):

We can solve async call in for loop with any of following 3 ways:

1. Callback

   var a = function(callback){
   //code
   callback();
   }

   var b = function(){
   for(loop details){
   that.a(function(){
   })
   }
   }
2. By recursive call of function instead of using for loop
3. By self iteration

   for(loop details){
   (function(i){
   //your code
   })(i);
   }